# Symfony 3.4 - Can we collect code coverage for functional testing?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, code-coverage

I am using symfony 3.4 for some of our projects. According to the docs, we should write functional tests for ours controllers. However, it seems that we cannot collect code coverage for functional test because symfony will run main code in another PHP processs.

- In phpunit process: `var_dump(xdebug_code_coverage_started()) => true`
- In controller code: `var_dump(xdebug_code_coverage_started()) =>
  false`.

UPDATE: It seems that the problem only occurs when I put tests in separate folder to `src` folder. It works when I put tests in the same bundle folder (`src/MyBubndle/Tests`)

**PHP Unit config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.0/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         processIsolation = "false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
        <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="weak"/>
        <!--<env name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel" />-->
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="test"/>
        <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="1"/>
        <env name="SYMFONY_ENV" value="test"/>
        <env name="MYSQL_SERVER" value="127.0.0.1"/>
        <env name="MYSQL_DATABASE" value="db"/>
        <env name="MYSQL_USER" value="root"/>
        <env name="MYSQL_PASSWORD" value="root"/>
        <env name="MYSQL_PORT" value="3306"/>
        <env name="JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH" value="jwt/public.pem"/>
        <env name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION" value="6.5.5"/>
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php" >.</directory>
            <exclude>vendor</exclude>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">.</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>app</directory>
                <directory>bin</directory>
                <directory>docker</directory>
                <directory>jwt</directory>
                <directory>var</directory>
                <directory>vendor</directory>
                <directory>web</directory>
                <directory>tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./var/logs/codeCoverage" charset="UTF-8"
             yui="true" highlight="true"
             lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
        <log type="coverage-text" target="php://stdout" showOnlySummary = "true" showUncoveredFiles="false"/>
        <log type="testdox-html" target="./var/logs/testdox.html" />
        <log type="junit" target="./var/logs/testreport.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="./var/logs/coverage.xml"/>
    </logging>
    <!--<listeners>-->
        <!--<listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\CoverageListener" />-->
    <!--</listeners>-->
</phpunit>
```

Also tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.0/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         processIsolation = "false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="app/" />
        <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="weak"/>
        <!--<env name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel" />-->
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="test"/>
        <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="1"/>
        <env name="SYMFONY_ENV" value="test"/>
        <env name="MYSQL_SERVER" value="127.0.0.1"/>
        <env name="MYSQL_DATABASE" value="db"/>
        <env name="MYSQL_USER" value="root"/>
        <env name="MYSQL_PASSWORD" value="root"/>
        <env name="MYSQL_PORT" value="3306"/>
        <env name="JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH" value="jwt/public.pem"/>
        <env name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION" value="6.5.5"/>
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php" >./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">./src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
               </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./var/logs/codeCoverage" charset="UTF-8"
             yui="true" highlight="true"
             lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="80"/>
        <log type="coverage-text" target="php://stdout" showOnlySummary = "true" showUncoveredFiles="false"/>
        <log type="testdox-html" target="./var/logs/testdox.html" />
        <log type="junit" target="./var/logs/testreport.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="./var/logs/coverage.xml"/>
    </logging>
    <!--<listeners>-->
        <!--<listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\CoverageListener" />-->
    <!--</listeners>-->
</phpunit>
```

Is there any workaround for this without using other testing framework?

All helps are highly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the contents of `phpunit.xml`.

Comment: @geoB I updated my phpunit config

Comment: try `<directory suffix=".php">./src/*</directory>` or `<directory suffix=".php">./*</directory>` on phpunit.xml

Comment: tried ./*, it still not woking

Comment: Facing the same problem with a very old legacy symfony `2.8.52` project and PhpUnit `4.8.36` - We are ready to start refactoring to progressively upgrade it from sf2 to 3, 4, and 5 and the first thing we wanted to do was creating "functional tests" around the legacy without touching the source code, so we could later refactor properly. We wanted to ensure 100% coverage for any file going to be refactored. Can't check the coverage, though.